# Is it possible to keepcommand line window open when running scheduled task executing python script if error accurs

Tags: python, windows

it's possible to keep all window open with [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961100/how-to-make-python-exe-stay-open-when-running-from-windows-task-scheduler), however I'd like to close the window if the script exit without error and stay when something went wrong